pomegranate all module is not defined
I'm using pomegranate in python, but the module is not working
All methods of pomegranate are not defined
from pomegranate import *

# Define the distributions for each node
guest = DiscreteDistribution({'A': 1./3, 'B': 1./3, 'C': 1./3})
prize = DiscreteDistribution({'A': 1./3, 'B': 1./3, 'C': 1./3})
monty = ConditionalProbabilityTable(...)

s1 = State(...)


NameError: name 'DiscreteDistribution' is not defined em

I installed Pomegranate 1.0.4

I believe you need to have from pomegranate.distributions import * as your first line, or do distributions.DiscreteDistribution. However, I can't find any evidence of such a class existing in the library or the documentation.

By "such a class" I mean DiscreteDistribution; sorry for lack of clarity.

In Pomegranate 1.0.4 (and likely any Pomegranate versions since the switch from cython to torch), discrete distributions have been renamed to categorical distributions.
Try the following:
from pomegranate import *

# Define the distributions for each node
guest = distributions.Categorical([[1./3, 1./3, 1./3]])
prize = distributions.Categorical([[1./3, 1./3, 1./3]])

The Monty Hall problem in the new version of pomegranate is documented here.
It is worth taking a look as much of the syntax seems to have changed (distributions no longer take dicts as inputs) and various attributes are deprecated (State, Node, etc.).
